# What does Ubuntu use for app status/tray icons?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, indicator

I noticed that Ubuntu 19.10 shows app status, a.k.a. tray icons, in the top right corner, which I don't see in a regular GNOME desktop. What does Ubuntu use for those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu ships a GNOME Shell extension called [Ubuntu AppIndicators](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1301/ubuntu-appindicators/) (package name: [`gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator)) which is activated by default in a standard Ubuntu session.

Note that this extension is a fork of the [KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) extension.